# How do I select all elements in List<Int32> into another List<Int32> with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I select all elements from list1 into list2 below by using LINQ?

```
List<Int32> list1 = GetList();
List<Int32> list2 = from e in list2 select ?????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As below :

```
List<Int32> list1 = GetList(); 
List<Int32> list2 = (from e in list2 select e).ToList();
```

or

```
    list1 =  GetList(); 
   List<Int32> list2 = new List<Int32>(list1);
```

Comment: I tried casting instead which did not work. thanks! I will accept your answer asap.

Comment: But note that `list1 = list2=  GetList();` is semantically different from all the other solutions. It does not create a new list, it just copies the reference.

Comment: @Henrik - yes so its not part of solution i removed it..thanks for poiting out

Answer (score 5):

Why no one suggest this solution:

```
List<int> list1 = GetTheList();
List<int> list2 = list1.ToList();
```

and why don't you feel strange about:

```
.Select(x => x)
```

this expression does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

No need to hit up LINQ just to copy all elements from a list:

```
List<Int32> list1 = GetList();
List<Int32> list2 = new List<Int32>(list1);
```

Answer (score 2):

With LINQ:

```
List<int> list1 = GetList();
List<int> list2 = list1.Select(x => x).ToList();
```

The easier way would be

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. But something like this:

```
List<Int32> list2 = (from e in list2 select e).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Int32> list2 =list1.Select (l =>l).ToList();
```